# Is there any way to call webapi from IDP when user is deleted

Tags: azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, adfs, auth0, idp

We are using SSO with auth0 for several IDP's such as ADFS, AzureAd and SAML etc. Where user is authenticated from individual IDP.

What we want is when a user is deleted from IDP, we should get some trigger on our end to do some cleanups. For instance, There could be an api end point that is called by IDP when ever a user is delete. So we can clean its data from our end also.

Do IDP's support any such functionality? 
Is my direction right? Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Azure AD at the moment does not have events for that. You'd have to run scheduled jobs to query users from there and see which ones no longer exist. That does require you to have access to list the users :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is provisioning, not authentication.

ADFS e.g. sits on top of AD. User notification is an AD function, not an ADFS one.

Yes, you could have some kind of trigger on AD that calls a web API but this is not part of ADFS.

Also, for Azure AD, a lot of the time the users are synced up from AD via AAD Connect.

If they are deleted from AD, they are deleted from Azure AD.

Comment: I have found this Microsoft documentation over SCIM. [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-scim-provisioning/#building-your-own-provisioning-solution-for-any-application). They say AzureAD can be configured to sync data from any repository provided with SCIM endpoints.  Can it help in any way?

Comment: When a user is deleted in AD, AAD Connect deletes them in Azure AD so this functionality is already there. There is no SCIM support for ADFS.